# turn one dimensional array to two dimensional array with loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I'm trying to pull out all SQL tables and column into array, should look like this:

```
array(
 'tableName' => array(
      'column1',
      'column2',
      'column3',
  )
);
```

I have wrote this code that pull tables and columns names from the database and push it to array.

```
<?php
    include("db-config.php");
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $tablesQuery = mysqli_query($link,"SHOW TABLES");
    echo '<pre>';
    while($table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tablesQuery)){
        $tables[] = $table['Tables_in_'.$DB['database']];
    }
    for($i = 0;$i<count($tables);$i++){
        $currentTable = $tables[$i];
        $columnsQuery = mysqli_query($link,"DESCRIBE `".$currentTable."`");
        while($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($columnsQuery)){
            $tables[$i][] = $column['Field']; //line 13
        }
        print_r($currentTable);
    }
?>
```

on line 13 the syntax `tables[$i]` some how turn into string instand of staying array, so that stopped me from pushing columns's data inside.

Thank for your guys help!

Comment: you can use string function `implode()` for array to string convert. 
Ref [http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php]

Comment: try to initialise $tables[$i] = array(); and then use array_push($tables[$i], $column['Field']); just try this one

Comment: thanks you guys! i have used @AdiechaHK answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the array correctly because `$tables[$i]` is a string value and not an array key:

```
$currentTable = $tables[$i]; // $tables[$i] is a string: you use it as a string below
mysqli_query($link,"DESCRIBE `".$currentTable."`"); //$currentTable = used as string
```

Then in your while loop, you attempt to use that string as an array key:

```
while($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($columnsQuery)) {
    $tables[$i][] = $column['Field']; //$tables[$i] == $currentTable as above = string
```

What you need to do instead is assign the value using $currentTable as the key:

```
while($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($columnsQuery)) {
    $tables[$currentTable][] = $column['Field'];
    // or
    $tables[$i][$currentTable][] = $column['Field'];
```

Answer (score 1):

For this task you need to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database and PDO [to get the result in the proper format](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP).

```
$sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='$DB[database]'";
$tables = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

will give you the exact result you want.